# Listener for media button (headset-hook) using service without Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, intentservice

How can I make service listen for media button (headset-hook) in android device .
I try to do that using this code but did not work.
Can you help me.

Service code:

```
public class RLservice extends IntentService {
    private Handler handler;

    public RLservice() {
        super("my service");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        handler = new Handler();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

        String intentAction = arg0.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) arg0
                    .getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);

            if (event == null) {
                return;
            }

            int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
            int action = event.getAction();
            long eventtime = event.getEventTime();

            if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
                    || keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK) {
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // Start your app here!
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is reciver code:

```
public class RLreciver extends BroadcastReceiver
{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent i=new Intent(RLservice.class.getName());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        arg0.startService(i);               
        }

}
```

This is manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ypu.RLservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver android:name=".RLreciver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100000" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".RLservice"
            android:process=":remote" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.ypu.RLservice.RLservice" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service is expecting an `Intent` with the `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` `Intent` action. You are not starting the service using such an `Intent`.

Change:

```
    Intent i=new Intent(RLservice.class.getName());
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    arg0.startService(i);
```

to:

```
    arg1.setClass(this, RLservice.class);
    arg0.startService(arg1);
```

This will effectively "redirect" the broadcast as a command to your service, with the action and extras intact.

Also:

- Get rid of `android:process=":remote"`, as it is not necessary here and is user-hostile
- Get rid of your `<intent-filter>` in your `<service>`, unless you intend for a million other apps to be calling this service

Comment: At first thank you very very much.
Please can you help me to override (add new behavior) to media button.
A new behavior is a long press must make a service, and I don't want to lose Voice dialer. In other word, when I press media button one click: media player must work, when I pressed it to short press: Voice dialer must appear, at last when I pressed it for one second: my service must work

thank you

Comment: @SWE: I am not aware that what you want is possible. You are welcome to ask a fresh StackOverflow question, though.