# Android - How to detect action media button long press

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, development-environment, headset

I'm developing an application that detect headset button single and double click (Code below). Single and double click works fine, but long click doesn't work. The code below is in a class that extends BroadcastReceiver. How can I resolve this problem? Thanks you very much.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    context1=context;
    intent1=intent;
    String intentAction=intent.getAction();
    if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equalsIgnoreCase(intentAction))
    {
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null) {
        return;
    }
    int action = event.getAction();
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        // do something

            d++;
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable r = new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    // single click *******************************
                    if (d == 1)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context1, "single click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    // double click *********************************
                    if (d == 2)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context1, "Double click!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    d = 0;
                }
            };
            if (d == 1)
            {

                handler.postDelayed(r, 500);
            }
    }
    /**
     * for long click
     */
    if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        if (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - event.getDownTime() > 2000)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Long click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    abortBroadcast();
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is Main.class

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
PreferenceFragment pf;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
    SingoloClick singoloClick= new SingoloClick();
    FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, singoloClick);
    ft.commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);//"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"
    MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
    filter.setPriority(999); //this line sets receiver priority
    registerReceiver(r, filter);
((AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MediaButtonIntentReceiver.class.getName()));
}

@Override public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    moveTaskToBack(true);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
    {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    /*else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }*/
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_singoloClick)
    {
        setTitle(""+getResources().getString(R.string.singoloClick));
        FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
        SingoloClick singoloClick= new SingoloClick();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, singoloClick);
        ft.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_doppioClick)
    {
        setTitle(""+getResources().getString(R.string.doppioClick));
        FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
        DoppioClick doppioClick= new DoppioClick();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, doppioClick);
        ft.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_lungoClick)
    {
    } 

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());*/
}

@Override public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

This is Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Main" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="0">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: You could store the actual time it is `ACTION_DOWN` and compare to the actual time it is `ACTION_UP` for your `> 2000` check.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use another key event KeyEvent.OTHER... What i found in doc:

```
  /**
     * This flag is set for the first key repeat that occurs after the
     * long press timeout.
     */
    public static final int FLAG_LONG_PRESS = 0x80;
```

**UPDATE:** Another solution, for capturing time, when button is pressed.

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        switch ( arg1.getAction() ) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //start timer
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // invoke intent
                }
            }, 5000); //time out 5s
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //stop timer
            timer.cancel();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

It looks like your problem is the way you are handling touch events in onTouchEvent. That method ACTION_UP - doesn't work!  You need to return true from onTouchEvent if you want to handle touch events. So, if you get an ACTION_DOWN and return false from onTouchEvent the system will not send you any more touch events related until the next ACTION_DOWN event.

If you want to receive any touch events other than ACTION_DOWN you will need to return true from onTouchEvent, that button. But you can't do that, so need to think about another solution.

**UPDATE 3**

As I said, need to create something other solution, because KEY_ACTION_UP doesn't work. Maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18423893/listener-for-media-button-headset-hook-using-service-without-activity) solution too.

Comment: But this code works for Button. I would detect the long press of hardware key (headset button).

Comment: Okey. If there are no other KeyEvents, try to use timer. Just initialize it on action event KEY_DOWN and stop timer on KEY_UP. Check timer size on long click.

Comment: Doesn't work. My app doesn't detect long press and always start ok google. How can I resolve this problem??

Comment: @AlessandroMarino can you provide code, sending intent, and that extras? I didn't see previous time, you send info  KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN and them abort BR.

Comment: now I put the code that call BR IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);//"android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"
        MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
        filter.setPriority(999); //this line sets receiver priority
        registerReceiver(r, filter); ...onReceive method is above in the question. I have seen that in logcat if I long press headset button there is more ActionDown and then one ActionUp, but my code doesn't detect ActionUp. Why? P.S. sorry for my English:)

Comment: Now I'm not in home. Just I arrive at home I will update the code

Comment: now I have updated the post. Now there is all Main Activity, Manifest and onReceive of BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @AlessandroMarino update answer, but i don't know what do next.

Answer (score 0):

For handle to long press on a key :

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```